# How to change the selected node color programmatically from remote json data for treeview in kendo ui?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I want to change the default selected and hover color for the treeview node in kendo ui based on the json data. so I added a template like below, it is not working, any help?

```
template: "<span style='color:#= item.color#;background-color:#= item.bgcolor #;selected-color:#= item.selectedColor#; hover-color:#= item.hoverColor#'> #= item.text # </span>",
```

Comment: If it is a programming exercise it might be ok but from the user experience point of view... are you sure that you want to do this?

Comment: We are using Kendo UI treeview for showing different state in different colors, some how few colors are not highlighted properly due it is color, so this becomes a requirement, I am just trying to find a way, if not we will go with default styling.

Comment: What I mean is that you are trying to customize color with a very small granularity. If the question is the state, use different color for states but not for `hover` or `selected`. This is confusing for users but also tricky and pretty fragile. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qZeK6/6/) to see how tricky and ugly it might become.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qZeK6/7/) even a little closer...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/qZeK6/8/  This is what our problem, to highlight yellow we are using gray, in that case gray is merged when we have text in gray.

Comment: Did you check my last version (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qZeK6/7/)? What about choosing different colors for text and backgrounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should overwrite KendoUI CSS styles for those nodes. It is not as easy as you were trying since `hover` is actually a modifier and not an html element.

You should define a template as:

```
 <script id="template" type="text/kendo-template">
    <style>
        span.ob-#=item.uid# {
            color: #= item.text #;
        }
        li[data-uid='#=item.uid#'] span.k-state-hover {
            background: #= item.hoverColor # !important;
        }
        li[data-uid='#=item.uid#'] span.k-state-selected {
            background: #= item.selectedColor #;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 4px #= item.selectedColor #;
        }
    </style>
    <span class="ob-#= item.uid#"> #= item.text #</span>
</script>
```

The trick here is that we are adding a style for each element using `li[data-uid="xyz"]` where `xyz` is the `uid` of each node. With this trick you might overwrite styles and also make them dependent of the node.

The style:

```
        span.ob-#=item.uid# {
            color: #= item.text #;
        }
```

defines the text color for a node.

The style:

```
        li[data-uid='#=item.uid#'] span.k-state-hover {
            background: #= item.hoverColor # !important;
        }
```

defines defines the style for `selected` state.

And finally

```
        li[data-uid='#=item.uid#'] span.k-state-selected {
            background: #= item.selectedColor #;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 4px #= item.selectedColor #;
        }
```

defines the style for the `selected` item.

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qZeK6/7/